# how to delete stroke on one side of the svg in chart using d3

Tags: d3.js, svg, charts, stroke

Hello i need to make chart like this

[image]

1. stroke on sides
2. lighter arc
3. no stroke between lighter and darker arc

Here is what i've got:

[Codepen.io](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JRgvLO)

HTML:

```
<div id="chart" style="width:400px; height: 400px; position:relative;"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var w = 400;
  var h = 400;
  var r = h/2;
  var color = ["#27c794", "#fd7b74", "#fd9f9a"]
  var color2 = ["#fd9f9a", "#27c794", "#fd7b74"]
  var image_width = 32;
  var image_height = 32;
  var data = [
    {"label": "Category A", "value":10, "icon": "http://files.gamebanana.com/img/ico/sprays/4f68c8d10306a.png"},
    {"label": "Category B", "value":45, "icon": "http://files.gamebanana.com/img/ico/sprays/4f69c5f09c7bf.png"},
    {"label": "Category C", "value":45, "icon": "http://files.gamebanana.com/img/ico/sprays/4ecb328ca104a.png"}
  ];


  var vis = d3.select('#chart').append("svg:svg").data([data]).attr("width", w).attr("height", h).append("svg:g").attr("transform", "translate(" + r + "," + r + ")");
  var pie = d3.pie().value(function(d){return d.value;});

  // declare an arc generator function
  var arc = d3.arc().outerRadius(r -20).innerRadius(r - 100);
  var arc2 = d3.arc().outerRadius(r -10).innerRadius(r - 20);
  // select paths, use arc generator to draw
  var arcs = vis.selectAll("g.slice").data(pie).enter().append("svg:g").attr("class", "slice");

  arcs.append("svg:path")
      .attr("fill", function(d, i){
          return color[i];
      }).attr("stroke", "#fff").style("stroke-width", "3")
      .attr("d", function (d) {
          return arc(d);
      })


  arcs.append("svg:path").attr("d", function (d) {
          return arc2(d);
      }).attr("fill", function(d, i){

          return color[i];
      }).style("opacity", "0.4");


      var x = d3.select("#chart").append("div");
      x.append("p").text("1212");
      x.append("p").text("11");
      x.selectAll("p").attr('style', function(d, i) {
        return "color:" + color[i];
      })


      // add the image
      arcs.append("svg:image").attr("transform", function(d, i){

          var x = arc.centroid(d)[0] - image_width/2;
          var y = arc.centroid(d)[1] - image_height/2;
          return "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")";
      })
      .attr("xlink:href",function(d) { if(d.data.value >= 15) {return d.data.icon;}})
      .attr("width", image_width)
      .attr("height", image_height);
```

Comment: What is your question? How to remove the outer stroke (#3)?  From your Codepen, it looks like you have numbers 1 and 2.

Comment: yes i need to remove stroke #3

Comment: The simplest solution would be to just increase arc2's `innerRadius` to around `(r - 22)`.

Comment: oh my god, so simple, thx